# how to convert a custom font into an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts

I'm wondering if anyone can shed any light on what possible node modules or libraries are being used to allow the font previewer render a custom font as an image instead of using the web font? I've noticed that an http request is initiated when this happens, so I'm assuming that the conversion is happening on the server.

Here is an example: (look for the font preview at the bottom of the page)
https://www.epicpxls.com/items/pocket-ui-kit-fintech-app?page=2

Creative Market also does this for font previews so people don't steal a font but can preview it before they purchase.

Could they be using node-canvas to do this and return an image? Other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, node-canvas could be used for this. It even has an [example](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/examples/font.js) of nearly exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Aw man didn't even see that example! Thank you so much for pointing it out :)